# Insert multiple columns in a pandas dataframe using insert method

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I want to insert multiple columns in selected positions in a `pandas dataframe`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product name': ['laptop', 'printer', 'printer',], 'price': [1200, 150, 1200],  'price1': [1200, 150, 1200]})
df.insert(0, 'AAA', -1)
df.insert(1, 'BBB', -2)
df
```

However I am wondering if I can insert multiple columns at once. I tried below,

```
df.insert([0, 1], ['AAA', 'BBB'], [-1, -2])
```

This generates error as,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3762, in insert
    value = self._sanitize_column(column, value, broadcast=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3899, in _sanitize_column
    value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 751, in sanitize_index
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (3)
```

Is there any way to insert multiple columns at once using `insert method?`

Comment: You can not insert multiple columns at once using `insert` method.

Comment: From the [`pandas.DataFrame.insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html), `loc` is only int, but you can try to loop to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Like already in the comments mentioned, `insert` is not possible for this.
If you have those two columns as `pd.dataFrame` or `pd.Series` you can use `pd.concat` like this:

```
pd.concat([s1,s2,df],axis=1)
```

where s1 is 'AAA' and s2 is 'BBB' with its values.
Be aware the index of s1, s2 and df has to be the same here.